# Program to write for you?

Tags: automation, macros

I need a program that can write what you input in it, and "writing" it back on another process, letter by letter, not copying and pasting it back. Basically, I have a insanely huge file that would take me about a month of non-stop keyboard typing and I can't simply control-C to the other program because it doesn't allow pasting text (go figure). I do realize it's quite an unusual question, but I need this to be done by a machine and not myself. Is there any way to be done?

Comment: Sounds like you need `tee`. Are you in a GUI environment? If the other program "doesn't allow pasting" how would anything paste or write text into it? Are you trying to brute-force a license key?

Answer (score 0):

Note: everything below assumes Windows, and I haven't tried any of these.

You could try [DataLoad](http://www.dataload.com/).

If that doesn't work for you, you could possibly knock up a little program yourself to parse in the file and simulate the keypresses. Relevant functions would probably be [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx). Or try having a look at [inputsimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBScript that will read the characters from the textfile and simulate pressing those keys into your program. Just make sure you run the script, then give your program focus.

To ensure you have enough time I have added a 2 second delay at the start so you can switch to your program after running it

```
WScript.Sleep 2000
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\text.txt", 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)
    WshShell.SendKeys strCharacters
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

A little AutoHotkey or AutoIt script can do that easily, and shouldn't be hard to write even from a beginner.

The AutoHotkey forum is also full of people that can write such script for you, just for the fun (since it wouldn't take much time to do it anyway).

Now, that's more or less what Bali C wrote, just with the capability to switch by itself to the target application and offering more options to send the keys.